Fantasy books that might have two girls and a boy, and there are a unicorn and maybe harpies
I read these books when I was about 9.  I think a lot of it was set in a magical forest with different creatures. And one of the books had a unicorn in it. One of the scenes in the book is where the girls trick the boy into saying his name out loud. I think the boy was evil.
I’m pretty sure on the covers of the book had a unicorn on the front and the books might have began with W.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know how old you are; approximately what year would that have been?

Xanth has magical forests, harpies, and unicorns, but I can't think of any W titles.

It could also be the Apprentice Adept series (also by Piers Anthony) though none of the titles have a W.  At least two of the books have unicorns on the cover.
